# Uploading a file using sockets

Tags: java, sockets

I am able to upload any type of file to the server using the code below. However, right after uploading finishes, I get an error message on the server that says

`java.net.SocketException: Socket is closed`
    `Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException`
    `at Server2Connection.run(server1.java:407)`
    `at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)`

The `server1.java: 407` refers to the line `switch (clientMsg)` in the server code. The file does get uploaded correctly. But it seems I am not doing something right with the `.close` instructions. The server does not disconnect after this but the client loops back one more time only to disconnect. Can anyone please tell me where I am messing up? Thanks.

Server Side:

```
public BufferedReader msgFromClient() throws IOException {
    BufferedReader receiveClientmsg = null;

    try {
        receiveClientmsg = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return receiveClientmsg;
}

public DataOutputStream outToClient() throws IOException {
    DataOutputStream sendClientmsg = null;

    try {
        sendClientmsg = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return sendClientmsg;
}

public void upload() throws IOException {
    byte[] mybytearray = new byte[8192];
    InputStream is = clientSocket.getInputStream();
    String file_name = msgFromClient().readLine();
    File rqstd_upld_file = new File(SERVER_FILE_LOCATION + file_name);

    if (rqstd_upld_file.exists()){
        outToClient().writeBytes("yes\n");
        outToClient().writeBytes("A file with the name " + file_name + " already exists on server\n");
        System.out.println("A file with the name " + file_name + " already exists");
    }
    else {
        outToClient().writeBytes("no\n");
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(SERVER_FILE_LOCATION +"\\"+ file_name);
        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

        int count;
        System.out.println("Downloading " + file_name + " ...");
        outToClient().writeBytes("Uploading. Please wait...\n");
        while ((count = is.read(mybytearray)) > 0){
            bos.write(mybytearray, 0, count);
        }
        System.out.println("Download Successful");
        is.close();
        bos.close();
    }
}
try {
        while (true) {
            //Message sent by the client
            String clientMsg = server.msgFromClient().readLine();               

            switch (clientMsg) {
            case "1":
                //'Upload file' command from client
                System.out.print("\nCommand from " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":"+ clientSocket.getPort()+" : ");
                System.out.println("Upload file");
                server.upload();
                break;

            case "1fail":
                //In case client fails to find the file it wants to upload
                System.out.print("\nCommand from " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":"+ clientSocket.getPort()+" : ");
                System.out.println("Upload file");
                System.out.println("Client could not upload: File did not exist on client machine\n");
                break;
}
catch(IOException e){
        System.out.println(e);
    }
```

Client side:

```
while (true) {
try{
Scanner scan0 = new Scanner(System.in);
String command = scan0.nextLine();

switch (command) {
case "1":
    //Upload file
    File file_to_upload = null;
    System.out.print("Enter file path: ");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String pathname = scan.nextLine();
    System.out.print("Enter file name: ");
    Scanner scan1 = new Scanner(System.in);
    String file = scan1.nextLine();
    Path path = Paths.get(pathname, file);
    file_to_upload = new File(path.toString());

    if (file_to_upload.exists()){   
        outToServer.writeBytes(command + '\n');
        outToServer.writeBytes(file + '\n');
        String existsOnServer = msgFromServer.readLine();

        switch (existsOnServer) {
        case "yes":
            System.out.println('\n'+ msgFromServer.readLine() + '\n');
            break;
        case "no":
            int count;
            System.out.println('\n'+ msgFromServer.readLine() + '\n');
            byte[] bytearray = new byte[8192];
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file_to_upload);
            BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in);
            OutputStream os = client1.getOutputStream();
                while ((count = bis.read(bytearray)) > 0){
                os.write(bytearray, 0, count);
            }
            System.out.println("Done Uploading");
            os.close();
            in.close();
            bis.close();
            break;
        }
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("File " + path + " does not exist\n");
        outToServer.writeBytes("1fail" + '\n');
    }
    break;

    case "2":
//...
}
                catch(IOException e){
                    System.out.println(e);
                    break;
                }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a new command to close connection with server.

```
switch (clientMsg) {
        case "1":
            //'Upload file' command from client
            System.out.print("\nCommand from " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":"+ clientSocket.getPort()+" : ");
            System.out.println("Upload file");
            server.upload();
            break;

        case "1fail":
            //In case client fails to find the file it wants to upload
            System.out.print("\nCommand from " + clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":"+ clientSocket.getPort()+" : ");
            System.out.println("Upload file");
            System.out.println("Client could not upload: File did not exist on client machine\n");
            break;
        case "-1":
            is.close();

            break;
```

Comment: just change `is` with `clientSocket.getInputStream()`.<br>

Answer (score 0):

You're creating new streams for each transaction and closing them. That closes the socket and that causes the exception you're getting next time.

But the technique isn't valid anyway. You should use the same streams for the life of the socket. You also need to arrange for the peer to know how much data is in the file you are sending, typically by sending it in advance and having the peer read exactly that many bytes, rather than reading to end of stream as you have it now.

Comment: I have edited my server code to use the same streams for the duration of a sockets existence. The same error still occurs.

Answer (score -1):

You might be closing the client strem too soon, not allowing for the server to finish reading form it. Try putting a timer before closing client's straem and socket. If it works, you should think of a nicer synchronization way to allow for server to read the entire file.

Comment: The server reads the entire file...only after that does the error occur. I have experimented with a range of file types and sizes starting from 1KB text files to 3.5 GB video files. The uploaded files are complete and functional (means they do not get corrupt). The error still occurs

Comment: You don't need timers or deferred closes. Data is not lost in TCP.